# libgdx - DragAndDrop objects in a scrollable area

Tags: drag-and-drop, libgdx

This is my scenario: I have a scrollable panel full of pieces, and then the rest of the window. I have to be able to scroll up/down this panel and then drag and drop each piece into the main window.

Something like this:

```
----------------------
|  X |               |
|  X |               |
|  X |               |
|  X |               |
|    |           X   |
----------------------
```

X is a piece. Originally they are in the scrollable area and then they'll be dropped on the right view.

I have created an actor for the left panel.
And each piece is another type of actor.

The left panel actor will be a scrollable background full of pieces. My problem is that the drag is always taken by the left panel but I cannot move the piece as all the inputs are taken by the panel.

My left panel actor implements InputProcessor for allowing the scroll and it has a DragAndDrop, but the drag is only recognised by the panel.

Comment: not know if this can help you, but the user @noone has something on, drag-and-drop on your blog, maybe it's what you want http://pixelscientists.com/blog/posts/drag-and-drop-inventory-with-libgdx-part-iv http://pixelscientists.com/blog/

Comment: I've noticed this before and filed an issue: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2240 it should be fixed with the most recent version. Maybe you need to set that additional flag though.

Comment: What should I do for using that latest code instead of the libgdx version I'm currently using? To clone the project and what else? Thanks noone! BTW, I'm not using a ScrollPane but a normal actor and trying to simulate the scroll with touchDown, touchDragged...

Comment: Nevermind. I have already access to that setCancelTouchFocus method. I'll see what i can do.